# Is this extension of $Sp(4,2)$ a semidirect product?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Somebody I trust has been insisting to me that a certain extension of $Sp(4,2)$ is actually a semidirect product, and I'm inclined to believe him, but I haven't been able to convince myself he's right, and I haven't gotten a satisfying explanation from him even after several attempts. I would appreciate your thoughts. Here's what we're looking at:

Let $Q$ be the order 16 group obtained by adding to the quaternion group $Q_8$ a central element $z$ whose square is $-1$. Here is a presentation for $Q$:

$$ Q = \langle i,j,z\mid z^4=1, i^2=j^2=z^2, [i,j]=z^2, [i,z]=1, [j,z]=1\rangle$$

It might be easier to see in terms of a 2-d complex representation:

$$ i\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} i& \\ &-i\end{pmatrix},\; j\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} &1\\ -1& \end{pmatrix},\; z\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}i& \\ &i\end{pmatrix}$$

Consider the central product $Q\otimes Q$, of order 64, with center $Z=\langle z\rangle$. We can think of $Q\otimes Q$ as generated by $i,j,i',j',z$ with $z$ central, and $i,j$ and $i',j'$ anticommuting in pairs and commuting with each other. $(Q\otimes Q)/Z$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{F}_2^4,+)$, generated by the residues of $i,j,i',j'$. The group I am interested in is

$$G = \operatorname{Aut}_Z(Q\otimes Q)$$

where by $\operatorname{Aut}_Z$ I mean just those automorphisms that fix the center elementwise. Since these automorphisms induce automorphisms of $Q\otimes Q/Z \cong \mathbb{F}_2^4$, there is a natural map $G\rightarrow GL(4,2)$, and since the commutator form of the central extension $Q\otimes Q \rightarrow\mathbb{F}_2^4$ is the standard alternating form (we can see this by thinking about the description of $Q\otimes Q$ above), the image of $G\rightarrow GL(4,2)$ lies in $Sp(4,2)$, and in fact it is this whole subgroup, since computation in $Q\otimes Q$ is described completely by knowledge of the center, the fact that all generators square to $z^2$, and the commutator form, and every element of $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ lifts in $Q\otimes Q$ to some element whose square is $z^2$ (thus any automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ preserving the commutator form lifts to a center-fixing automorphism of $Q\otimes Q$).

The kernel of the homomorphism $G\rightarrow Sp(4,2)$ is the group of inner automorphisms of $Q\otimes Q$, which is isomorphic to $(Q\otimes Q)/Z\cong \mathbb{F}_2^4$ again. So we have an exact sequence

$$1\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_2^4\rightarrow G\rightarrow Sp(4,2)\rightarrow 1$$

> The question is whether this sequence splits.

I am being told it does. Another way to say this is I am being told that $G\cong ASp(4,2)= \mathbb{F}_2^4\rtimes Sp(4,2)$. However, to believe this, I need to see an action of $G$ on $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ corresponding to $ASp(4,2)$'s action. $G$ has to act in such a way that its restriction to the kernel is the regular action of $\mathbb{F}_2^4$ on itself.

> Can you see such an action?

I haven't found it yet. Clearly $G$ acts on $\mathbb{F}_2^4=(Q\otimes Q)/Z$ via its natural action on $Q\otimes Q$, but this is the action we used to define the homomorphism to $Sp(4,2)$, so obviously it is trivial when restricted to the kernel of this homomorphism. Likewise $G$ acts on the kernel by conjugation, but again this action is trivial when restricted to this kernel, since it is abelian. (Actually, I suspect this is the exact same action up to an automorphism of $Sp(4,2)$.) On the other hand, the kernel acts regularly on itself, but if I extend this in the obvious way to all of $G$, I end up with the regular action of $G$ on itself, not an action on $\mathbb{F}_2^4$.

Any thoughts you have are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just did a computer calculation, and the extension in question turned out to be non-split. However, it did split when restricted to the derived subgroup of ${\rm Sp}(4,2)$. (Note that ${\rm Sp}(4,2) \cong S_6$, with derived group isomorphic to $A_6$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt - do you do that sort of calculation in Magma, or GAP, or what? And how is it set up? (I could have saved us all some time if I knew how to do this myself! :)

Comment: I used Magma. I'll e-mail you the script.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the group $Q \otimes Q$ is SmallGroup$(64,266)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of showing in Magma that the extension in question is non-split. The group $Q \otimes Q$ is SmallGroup$(64,266)$.

```
Q := SmallGroup(64,266);
H,m1,m2 := Holomorph(Q);
N := Image(m1); // N is a regular normal subgroup of H isomorphic to Q
S := Stabiliser(H,1); //S is isomorphic to Aut(Q)
Z := Centre(N); //cyclic of order 4
G := Centraliser(S,Z); //G is required extension 2^4.Sp(4,2)
M := MinimalNormalSubgroups(G)[1];
Complements(G,M); //empty
```